# IPython crashes on tab completion

Tags: ipython

I've encountered an annoying issue causing ipython to crash on tab completion. Occurs frequently and persistently, yet without any clear indication what causes it. Has anyone else encountered this? If so, is there a workaround? I'm running IPython 6.2.1 on Python 3.6.4.

Here's the error message just before the crash, right after a tab button is pressed on a class attribute `>In [35]: class_instance.attri<tab>`:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7f5e4832e470>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foobar/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3501, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
In [15]: class_instance.specfiTcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
[1]    23894 abort (core dumped)  ipython
```

Apologies for not being able to reliably reproduce this one - as I said earlier, it seems to occur semi-randomly at tab completion. That being said, importing `matplotlib` and/or running in `--pylab` mode might be relevant.

Comment: Does this only occur if a matplotlib figure is actually open?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest no, having a figure open is not a requirement. However, ipython does seem to crash more often when matplotlib is set in interactive mode.

Comment: We would need some kind of code to test. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Mike-SMT unfortunately it's not as simple as putting together a MCVE - the crashes appear to be random and have no pattern in them, occurring interactively within an ipython console. Didn't happen with the older versions of IPython, so I suppose it's an issue on that side.

Comment: It is going to be very hard to troubleshoot this problem without some kind of code to test.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I am well aware of that. Perhaps I should not have tagged the question with matplotlib and tkinter, as it seems to be mainly an ipython issue. I'll remove those tags to avoid more confusion.

Comment: I found an open github issue that describes the problem: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10871

Answer (score 1):

Updating IPython (problematic version `6.2.1`, currently using `7.19.0`) fixed it for me and I haven't had the issue re-appear even since (2018+).

I'm posting an answer describing what solved it for me because the question seems to generate some traffic to this day.